# Using 2 type of ViewModel Protocol with same ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make my viewmodel interfaces more conformant to SOLID by removing unused methods by splitting them down into smaller interfaces.

However I cant seem to get this to work with ViewModel Interfaces and ViewControllers

if i have these 2 example protocols

```
protocol PlayerViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    var title: String { get }
    var type: Enum { get }
    var stateIs: Bool { get }
}

protocol OnlinePlayerViewModel: PlayerViewModel {
    var isFromA: Bool { get }
    var isFromB: Bool { get }
    var hasIntro: Bool { get }
    var hasSkipped: Bool { get set }

    func sendEvent()
    func sendAnalytics()
}
```

So in my VC i need to access all the properties in OnlinePlayerViewModel so in my class i need a reference such as

```
init(_ viewModel: OnlinePlayerViewModel) {
        _viewModel = viewModel

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

private var _viewModel: OnlinePlayerViewModel
```

However i have another ViewModel for offline behaviours that only needs `PlayerViewModel` so i cant init with it as it wont set to `private var _viewModel: OnlinePlayerViewModel`

What the solution here? so i dont have to force offline view model to conform to OnlinePlayerViewModel and have a lot of uneeded blank functions and values, whislt reusing my viewcontroller...or is this just not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use inheritance with classes rather than composition with protocols, but really I suspect you are making things more complicated by trying to simplify.

Comment: but is simplification against SOLID just being messy for convenience?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simple. You can have two initializers one for the online and an other for the offline viewModel. You can have two viewModel variables one will hold the online and the other the rest of the functionality. For the online mode both viewModel variables will reference the same object. For the offline only the _playerViewModel will have value, checking if the _viewModel is nil can turn off the functionality that is not available in the offline mode.

For example:

```
init(_ viewModel: OnlinePlayerViewModel) {
        _viewModel = viewModel
        _playerViewModel = viewModel

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
init(_ viewModel: PlayerViewModel) {
        _playerViewModel = viewModel
        _viewModel = nil

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

private var _viewModel: OnlinePlayerViewModel?
private var _playerViewModel: PlayerViewModel
```

Comment: hmm im not sure this makes for better code overall as then theres loads of optionals added for the viewmodel calls! but i see how it could work

Comment: The optional view model indicate that it could be missing its value, which according to your implementation is true, since you can have the same view controller but with a view model that does not have the online functionality, the "not having" part is indicated by a view model that does not have value. Since the structure of the program reflect the application logic I think it makes it a better code.